# Expected type 'str', got 'CharField' instead

Tags: python, django-models, type-hinting

In my Django project in PyCharm, I have enabled type hinting. In a Django model, I have defined a `CharField`. In a method in the model, I want to use that as an argument in a function that expects a string. I get the following warning however:

```
Expected type 'str', got 'CharField' instead
```

I realize that the two types are not the same. What would be the best way to not get the field itself, but the contents of the field as argument to that function. Note that behaviorly, everything is correct already, the receiving function already treats the argument as a string.

Comment: I can't make pycharm complain in this way when I tried to create a test case, could you please provide some minimal sample code that exhibits this behavior?

Comment: If you've worked out what the problem was, please can you [write your own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) rather than editing your question? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found out that this issue was resolved after I had enabled Django support in my project in PyCharm.

[image: PyCharm screenshot of settings where to Enable Django Support]

Comment: this feature is not available in the community edition